# How to find point closest to another in a group of points?

Tags: python, coordinates

Say I have a list of X,Y points. I then add a new point, how would i find out which old point the newly added point is closest too? I've seen a few similar questions but couldn't get any to work. I'm looking for something like:

```
pnts = [[11145,1146], [11124,1155], [11212,1147], etc]
new_pnt = [11444, 1160]
new_pnt.closest()
```

I've tried scipy and KDTree and kept getting various errors. Brand new to Python, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) to calculate the distance between any two points and then use that value to determine which one is closest.

Comment: Do you want *Euclidian distance* (assuming an idealized plane) or a non-planar distance? If your coordinates are geographical, for example, you might want to use a different mechanism (Haversine at least). Also, how many points are you going to be comparing to? For a small number of points, checking linearly won't be a problem, but for a very large number of points it will quickly become intractable and you'll need some kind of heuristic (e.g. using an RTree or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and quickest way would be for you to define a function to measure the distance to every point and return the closest one. For example (assuming euclidean distance):

```
>>> pnts = [[11145,1146], [11124,1155], [11212,1147]]
>>> new_pnt = [11444, 1160]
>>> def closest(points, new_point):
    closest_point = None
    closest_distance = None
    for point in points:
        distance = ((point[0] - new_point[0])**2 + (point[1] - new_point[1])**2)**0.5
        if closest_distance is None or distance < closest_distance:
            closest_point = point
            closest_distance = distance
    return closest_point

>>> closest(pnts, new_pnt)
[11212, 1147]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have NumPy available? If so:

```
import numpy as np
index = np.argmin(np.sum((np.array(pnts) - np.array(new_pnt))**2, axis=1))
print(index)  # 2
```

That is, the point `pnts[2]` is closest to `new_pnt`. The distance is given by the square root of the sum of differences between a pair of x and y coordinates. Here I leave out the square root, as the point with the smallest squared distance is also the point with the smallest distance.